# what is the meaning of variable = variable + 2

Tags: variables, count

What is the meaning of commentCount = commentCount + 2; and  commentNewCount: commentCount

```
//Jquery start at here

  <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){

           var commentCount = 2;
                $("button").click(function(){
                 commentCount = commentCount + 2;
                $("#comments").load("load_comments.php", {
                   commentNewCount: commentCount
             });
         });
    });

//End
 </script>
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you should review a basic JavaScript tutorial.  This isn't a good way to learn JS from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

1. `commentCount = commentCount + 2;` takes the value of `commentCount`, adds 2 to it, and stores the result back in `commentCount`.
2. This

   ```
   {
       commentNewCount: commentCount
   }
   ```

   ...is called an *object initializer* (or *object literal*). This one creates an object with a property called `commentNewCount` and assigns it the current value of `commentCount`.

   In the quoted code, it then passes that to jQuery's `load` function to be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, = is called an assignment operator. It's not the same as an equals sign in mathematics. It means the things on the right of it are stored in the variable on the left. So, first `commentCount` stores the number 2 with `var commentCount = 2`, then later `commentCount + 2` is calculated to be 4, and saved to `commentCount`.

`{commentNewCount: commentCount}` is a JavaScript object literal. You can read about that here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp